# Playing a Video

Tags: android, video, mobile, android-videoview

I am new in Android programming.

I want learn how to add video in my application.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.user_pc.popup;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView videoViewId = findViewById(R.id.videoViewId);

    videoViewId.setVideoPath("android.resources://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);

     MediaController mController = new MediaController(this);
     mController.setAnchorView(videoViewId);
     videoViewId.setMediaController(mController);

     videoViewId.start();
}
}
```

I write this code to play video, but it is not working.

Can someone help me with this?

@Kaushal Gosaliya, I think it will help you, thanks!

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoViewId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user_pc.popup">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

[Here is my path file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOIa1.png)

[Here is video, I do not know how to share path file with extension like "video.mp4", so I have to send link, if you can convert it to .mp4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twZggnNbFqo)

Comment: Is the VideoView screen always black?

Comment: Is video path correct?

Comment: Error msg Can't play this video?

Comment: Check my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I use the VideoView without adding Internet permission, I get the error that the video can not be played, it is solved with this permission, as long as your code or file path is correct.

> Change `android.resources` by `android.resource`

Simplified Java code:

```
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

android.net.Uri uri = android.net.Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);

video.setVideoURI(uri);

video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

video.start();
```

Add this permission in your Android Manifiest.xml:

```
... package="com.example.user_pc.popup">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application ...
```

Second option:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "video.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity replace this line:

```
videoViewId.setVideoPath("android.resources://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
```

with this:

```
vv.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.example.user_pc.popup/"+R.raw.panda);
```

Comment: Thanks because you want to help, but this also not work.